# Comparar datos tipo JSON ingresados en el cuerpo de una requisición con el _id de otra collection en MongoDB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Tengo dos collections que se relacionan, y al hacer un post, quiero validar que si el dato JSON que ingreso en el cuerpo de la requisición no existe en la otra collection, me devuelva un error personalizado.

***¿Cómo hago esa comparación?***

Ejemplo: Tengo una collection *alumnos* que tiene un campo *curso* y que al hacer post para crear un alumno, si ingreso un curso que no existe en otra collection llamada curso, me lance un error personalizado.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
if (!req.body.curso == curso._id || req.body.curso == null)
res.send("No existe este curso")
}
```

> Esta es mi idea pero no estoy logrando captar ese error. Entra en un bug.

Los otros errores están funcionando bien, los guarda en el array y los muestra, pero el error de verificar si es un curso válido entra en bug aún cuando le añadí el `return`... Es decir si coloco un id valido de 24 caracteres funciona, da un status 201 y registra, pero si le quito caracteres al object id o le añado caracteres entra en el bug... Les muestro un ejemplo de la requisición tipo JSON que hago para que me dé error quitándole caracteres al `objectid` que sería el `_id` de la collections *curso* que está relacionada con el campo *curso* de la collections *alumno*.

Aquí el código completo:

```js
    {
     "nombre": "Juan Perez",
     "identificacion": "V-12345678",
     "curso": "633b6cc61dd5941753"
    }
```

```js
    const express = require("express");
    const alumnoSchema = require("../models/alumno");
    const router = express.Router();

    //Registrar un alumno
    router.post("/alumno", async(req, res) => {
      const alumno = alumnoSchema(req.body);
      const errores = []
      alumno
      try {
        if (!req.body.monbre || req.body.nombre == null) {
          errores.push("Ingrese el nombre del alumno")
        }

        if (!req.body.identificacion || req.body.identificacion == null) {
          errores.push("Ingrese la identificacción del alumno")
        }

        if (!req.body.curso) {
          errores.push("Ingrese el curso del alumno produto")
        }

        if (!req.body.curso == curso.id || req.body.cuso == null) {
          return errores.push("No existe este cuso")
        }
        if (errores.length > 0) {
          res.status(400)
          res.send(errores)
          return
        } else {
          await alumno.save()
          res.status(201).send("Alumno registrado con exito")
        }
      } catch {
        if (!req.body == alumnoSchema)
          res.status(500).send("Error del lado del servidor")
      }
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Sería bueno publicar el error que te aparece. Me imagino que el error es por que despues de esa linea tienes más codigo. Para que no pase ese error agrega `return` a la linea así  `return res.send("No existe este curso")`

Comment: Gracias por responder Legna.  Estoy nuevo en esto. No me aparece error solo entra en bug y tengo que pararlo, le agregue el return y sigue igual. No se si luego puedas colaborarme con una video llamada y te comparto el codigo completo. O si puedo pasarte el codigo por github. O copiarlo todo aqui.

Comment: Hola. Lo puedes pegar por aquí. Hay un link de editar directamente abajo de las etiquetas.

Comment: Ahi esta completo. Muchas gracias Legna.

Comment: "Los otros errores están funcionando bien": ¿ _las otras validaciones_ ? "Entra en un bug": ¿ _tiene un bug_ ? Por cierto, los snippets son solo para código que se puede ejecutar en la pregunta misma. No olvides [edit] para corregir/mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Ah ok. Entiendo. Pense que era para verlo mejor. Soy nuevo aqui, está es mi primera pregunta. Pero muchas gracias, lo tendré presente para las proximas. Si todas las validaciones funcionan bien. Solo esa es la que no funciona. Cuando digo bug quizas no es la expresion correcta, me refiero a que al hacer la requisicion e informar un objectid que no existe, se cuelga y no da ningun error tengo que detenerlo manualmente.

Comment: ¿Dónde declaras la variable `curso` y qué tipo de dato es `curso.id`? La comparación la haces entre una cadena (`body.curso` es una cadena) y lo que sea que es la variable `curso.id`. Es una comparación "no estricta", ¿porqué?.

Comment: cuando digo req.body.curso es el valor que ingreso en el cuerpo de la requisicion para el campo curso de la collections alumno, que debe ser el mismo que el objectid(_id) de la collection curso. ya que estan relacionadas asi estas dos collections en el esquema. De modo que curso.id o curso._id que es la forma como realmente la da mongo, no se cual es la forma correcta de llamarla despues, pero si se que es un ObjectId de la collection curso.

Answer (score 0):

Elimina el `!` de la primera evaluacion. Y elimina el return, ya que en este caso estas acumulando los errores en un arreglo para luego enviarlos.

```
// Aqui debe buscar que sea diferente con el operador !=
if (req.body.curso != curso.id || req.body.curso == null) {
          errores.push("No existe este cuso")
        }
```

## Recomendacion

Parece que no estas mandando el error capturado. Intenta con estas correcciones.

```javascript
const express = require("express");
const curso = require("../models/curso"); //aqui llamo al esquema curso para tomar el _id
    const alumnoSchema = require("../models/alumno");
    const router = express.Router();

    //Registrar un alumno
    router.post("/alumno", async(req, res) => {
      const alumno = alumnoSchema(req.body);
      const errores = []
      alumno
      try {
        if (!req.body.monbre || req.body.nombre == null) {
          errores.push("Ingrese el nombre del alumno")
        }

        if (!req.body.identificacion || req.body.identificacion == null) {
          errores.push("Ingrese la identificacción del alumno")
        }

        if (!req.body.curso) {
          errores.push("Ingrese el curso del alumno produto")
        }

        if (req.body.curso == curso.id || req.body.curso == null) {
          //Aqui no ocupas el return ya que no estas enviando la respuesta
          // return errores.push("No existe este cuso")
          errores.push("No existe este cuso")
        }
        if (errores.length > 0) {
          res.status(400)
          res.send(errores)
          return
        } else {
          await alumno.save() 
          // Aunque o es necesario por la lógica que estás manejando, 
          // aquí hay que poner un return para mantener buenas prácticas
          return res.status(201).send("Alumno registrado con exito")
        }
      //No estas capturando el error, deberías poner esto
      } catch (error) {
        // Este if no se que hace, pero parece que no funciona
        // if (!req.body == alumnoSchema)
          return res.status(500).send("Error del lado del servidor" + error)
      }
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Ok. lo he hecho así. Le agregue detectar lo de los los errores al catch muchas gracias. Si le cambio un caracter por otro, se supone que el id no es valido, solo que sigue siendo de 24 caracteres. pero igual cae en status 200. no debería. Si le quito caracteres o le agrego me cae en el catch como error 500. y este es el mensaje:  Error del lado del servidorValidationError: curso: Cast to ObjectId failed for
    value "633b6cc61dd594153f1739e" (type string) at path "curso" because of
    "BSONTypeError"

Comment: Es decir, ahora está aceptando cualquier valor Object id como valido que no debería ser, y si lo modifico quitandole caracteres da el error 500 del catch pero no el 400 con el mensaje "No existe este curso"

Comment: No entra por que tenemos que hacer la negación en vez de comparar que sean iguales. Revisa de nuevo la validación.

Comment: Le coloque la negacion pero queda igual. envia un 200 si tiene 24 caracteres y entra  en el 500 si le quito caracteres y envía este mensaje:     Error del lado del servidorValidationError: curso: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "633b6cc61dd594153f1739e" (type string) at path "curso" because of "BSONTypeError"

Comment: Puedes editar t u pregunta con toda la traza del error?

Comment: Y de donde sale `curso.id`?

Comment: Esto puede servirte para ese problema : https://stackoverflow.com/a/71933433/4326551

Comment: Estaba haciendo la negacion incorrecta la hice asi como me sugeriste != y ahora si entra en el error pero me da error tambien si el id es valido me da el mismo error.

Comment: Ahora tengo el siguiente error:     const castError = new CastError();
                    ^

CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "aaaaa" (type string) at path "_id" for model "curso"

Comment: Entonces creo que la pregunta sería como valido que lo introducido en el cuerpo de la requisicion en el campo curso sea distinto de un ObjetoId valido para que me de el error esperado?